# Linear search does not give desired output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no); //function prototype

int main()//main function 
{
    int n;
    int no=20;//no to be searched
    int i;
    int result;
    int arr[]={10,20,80,30,60,50,110,100,130,170};
    n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    result=linear_searching(arr,n,no);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        printf("the element is not present in this array");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the element is present in the array on this index %d",i);
    }
    return 0;
}

int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==no)
            return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

my program is not working when i want to search 10 the it gives the index but when i go for another no then it does not give me index it says element is not present in the array as i have written in my if block on my main function please help

Comment: why you didn't use n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int); in place of n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); it does not look right to me honestly

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti it's a standard C programming idiom.

Comment: Correct. For the sake of clarity, the statement n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is simply the position of `return -1` inside the for loop:

```
int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==no)
            return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

should be:

```
int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==no)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This explains why your search function only works when the item is found in the first array element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==no)
            return i;
        
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the place of `return -1` in that function, as after the first iteration of the loop (if the element you looked for is not on the 0th index) you return from the function with -1. You should change it to:

```
int linear_searching(int arr[],int n,int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==no)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then you will search in all possible elements, and if you do not hit your number, it will return `-1` after whole array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int linear_searching(int arr[], int n, int no)// function for searching
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == no){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    
    int n;
    int no = 20;//no to be searched
    int i;
    int result;
    
    int arr[]={10,20,80,30,60,50,110,100,130,170};
    
    n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    result = linear_searching(arr, n, no);
    if(result == -1)
    {
        printf("the element is not present in this array");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the element is present in the array on this index %d", result);
    }
return 0;
}
```